# End Time should be greater than Start Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two time pickers one is for start Time and another for End Time, The End Time must be always greater than start time. I am using eonasdan datetimepicker. If start date is greater than end date it should not allow or we need to get pop. Please help me out with this

Here's what i have done so far

```js
$('#starttime,#endtime').datetimepicker({
  format: 'HH:mm'
});

var start_time = $('#Start_Time').val();

var end_time = $('#End_Time').val();

if (Date.parse(start_time) > Date.parse(end_time)) {
  alert('start time should be smaller');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="start_time" class="col-form-label">Start Time</label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='starttime'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="Start_Time" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="end_time" class="col-form-label">End Time</label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='starttime'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="End_Time" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what's your problem? It looks like you have some code that tries to achieve this. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Youve forgotten to include jQuery and your datepicker plugin in your [mcve]

Comment: You give the same id for start date and end date, so you change your end date id

Answer (score 3):

You may need to update the `endTime.minDate` on each `startTime.change` event.
Try to follow my example:

```js
function TimePickerCtrl($) {
  var startTime = $('#starttime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH:mm'
  });
  
  var endTime = $('#endtime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH:mm',
    minDate: startTime.data("DateTimePicker").date()
  });
  
  function setMinDate() {
    return endTime
      .data("DateTimePicker").minDate(
        startTime.data("DateTimePicker").date()
      )
    ;
  }
  
  var bound = false;
  function bindMinEndTimeToStartTime() {
  
    return bound || startTime.on('dp.change', setMinDate);
  }
  
  endTime.on('dp.change', () => {
    bindMinEndTimeToStartTime();
    bound = true;
    setMinDate();
  });
}

$(document).ready(TimePickerCtrl);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="start_time" class="col-form-label">Start Time</label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='starttime'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="Start_Time" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="end_time" class="col-form-label">End Time</label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='endtime'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="Start_Time" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!!! @Hitmands This is working fine but we should not get the time by default, and it should display the time with the click on the addon,  this happens by removing date property, but with the click on the addon i am getting the date displayed in both start time and end time, instead it should happen for a particular input filed i.e, for start time and end time. can you please help me out with this . Thank you

Comment: I edited my example, if it is enough, please accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but the only problem is when i update the start time, the endtime is also getting updated with it, rather when i start updating the start time , the end time field should get cleared and the updated time should get entered when we click on the addon of it, please help me out with this thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 var startDate = Date.parse($('#txtdatetimepicker1').val());
 var endDate = Date.parse($('#txtdatetimepicker2').val());
 if (startDate >= endDate) { alert("Please enter proper date") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the past dates than start date in `end_time` text box. Something like this, please replace textbox id as in your html code.

```
$( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $('#endDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());
  },
  minDate: 0
});
$( "#endDate" ).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    if($( "#startDate" ).val() == ''){
      $( "#endDate" ).val('');
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some thing with timepicker

[Fiddle Link Over here...!](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kxL0f1gc/)

```
https://fiddle.jshell.net/kxL0f1gc/

<link href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">

<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Try this HTML Code

```
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row"> 
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                                <label class="control-label">Start Time</label>
                                <input id="start" name="start" ng-model="start" type="text" required="required" class="form-control start" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                                <label class="control-label">End Time</label>
                                <input id="end" name="end" ng-model="end" type="text" required="required" class="form-control end" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```js
$('.start, .end').timepicker({
  showInputs: false,
  minuteStep: 1,
});
$( "#end, #start" ).change(function() {
var time = $("#start").val();
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if(hours<10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
if(minutes<10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
var time2 = $("#end").val();
if(time2=="")
  {
   var time2 = "00:00 AM";
  }
  var hours2 = Number(time2.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
  var minutes2 = Number(time2.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
  var AMPM2 = time2.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
  if(AMPM2 == "PM" && hours2<12) hours2 = hours2+12;
  if(AMPM2 == "AM" && hours2==12) hours2 = hours2-12;
  var sHours2 = hours2.toString();
  var sMinutes2 = minutes2.toString();
  if(hours2<10) sHours2 = "0" + sHours2;
  if(minutes2<10) sMinutes2 = "0" + sMinutes2;
  var comparehour = sHours2-sHours;
  var comparemin = sMinutes2-sMinutes;
  if(comparehour<0)
  {
   $("#end").val(time);
  }
 else if((comparehour==0) && (comparemin<0))
  {
   $("#end").val(time);
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set time validation with AM and PM

```
   var startTime = $('.StartTime').datetimepicker({ 
     "allowInputToggle": true,
     "showClose": true,
     "showClear": true,
     "showTodayButton": true,
     "format": ' hh:mm A',
     "useCurrent": false 
   })

   var endTime =  $('.EndTime').datetimepicker({ 
    "allowInputToggle": true,
    "showClose": true,
    "showClear": true,
    "showTodayButton": true,
    "format": ' hh:mm A',
    "useCurrent": false })
   .on("dp.change", function (e) {
        minDate: startTime.data("DateTimePicker").date()
        bindMinEndTimeToStartTime(startTime);
        bound = true;
        setMinDate(endTime,startTime);
    });


    function setMinDate(endTime,startTime) {
        return 
        endTime.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(startTime.data("DateTimePicker").date()
      );
   }

  function bindMinEndTimeToStartTime(startTime) {
      var bound = false;
      return bound || startTime.on('dp.change', setMinDate);
  }
```